# How to get data from two tables based on a unique criteria. Join is not a proper solution I feel

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, backend

I have 2 tables one is User and another is TreatmentStatusTable. User tables has 2 types of user first is a "doctor" and the other one is "patient". A doctor can treat a patient and the status is put in the TreatmentStatusTable.

Every time a doctor see a patient he is marked. In next query I only want to see the patients which has not been seen by the doctor so far. How should I achieve it efficiently?

Here is my scenerio:

User

```
id
name 
dateObirth
userType- doctor/patient
```

TreatmentStatusTable

```
treated_by- User.id (UserId of doctor)
treated_to User.id (UserId of patient)
treatment_status  cured/referd
```

Now I want to find all the remaining patients in User table where the Doctor has NOT
got the chance to see the patient

So the query should be something like

```
Select * 
from User 
where user.id not in (
                        Select User.id 
                        from TreatmentStatusTable 
                        where treated_by= User.id).   <- this the doctor's user.id
```

so basically to get all the users from the table User which has not been yet seen by the doctor.

The query above works for me. But I believe once the result size of later query(2nd query) will be in a few thousand this query will fail

Could anyone suggest me a better way to query this data in a more efficient way?

Comment: At what point in the process do you create the `row` in the `TreatmentStatusTable`?

Comment: Using `SELECT *` inside the subquery is not valid anyway, because `*` will return three columns per row. You can't compare that to a single column in the predicate of the outer query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `not exists`.  Something like this:

```
select u.*
from users u
where u.user_type = 'patient' and
      not exists (select 1 
                  from treatmentstatustable tst
                  where tst.treated_to = u.id
                 );
```

For performance, you want an index on `treatmentstatustable(treated_to)`.  The performance should be fine for tens of thousands of rows (and more).

Comment: Thanks. This query is working. I want an index on treatmentstatustable(treated_to)? How would that help the prformance?

Comment: That makes the `not exists` subquery simply an index lookup.  Hard to get faster than that.

Comment: Thanks. This answered my question. Could you also tell me which one between these 2 would work better in my scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you think a join is not a proper solution.

I would write it this way:

```
Select u.* 
from User AS u
left outer join TreatmentStatusTable AS t 
  on u.id = t.treated_to
where t.treated_to is null
```

An outer join returns NULLs for the columns in `t` if there is no matching row for the given user. If we use a where condition to restrict the results to only those cases where `t` has NULLs, then it must be a user who has not been seen by a doctor.

This is a common way to write an "exclusion join" to find rows with no match.

Comment: How would I use it to get only userType="patient" and LIMIT to fetch only N records at. a time

Comment: You should be able to figure that out.